# Persistent relational projections in RailsEventStore

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cqrs, event-sourcing, rails-event-store

I am trying to build a CQRS and event sourced Rails 5.2.x application using RailsEventStore.

Now I would like to project my event stream into a relational model, ideally just using ActiveRecord and the PostgreSQL database I also used for my event store.

In the documentation of RailsEventStore I only found on-the-fly, non-persistent projections.

Is there any infrastructure available to continuously build and update a relational representation of an event stream? It needs to remember which events have already been applied to the relational model across restarts of the application.

In case you know how to do it, please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no out-of-the-box background process in RailsEventStore to support [persistent projections](https://blog.arkency.com/why-event-sourcing-basically-requires-cqrs-and-read-models/) the same way EventStore database does them.

There are however pieces you can fit together to achieve something similar — [event handlers](https://railseventstore.org/docs/subscribe/) and [linking](https://railseventstore.org/docs/link/).

My colleague Rafał put together a few posts documenting this approach:

- https://blog.arkency.com/using-streams-to-build-read-models/
- https://blog.arkency.com/read-model-patterns-in-case-of-lack-of-order-guarantee/

If you'd like to implement such projection as a separate background process rather to rely on event handlers (whether synchronous or not) then [Distributed RailsEventStore](https://github.com/RailsEventStore/rails_event_store/tree/9754a0271e6516a09b12fd437708379bedc9d75f/contrib/distributed_rails_event_store) with [PgLinearizedRepository](https://railseventstore.org/docs/repository/#using-pglinearizedeventrepository-for-linearized-writes) might be a good starting point.

Comment: Thanks for the links. Sadly your first article never mentions how and from whom Builder is ever called and if it is supposed to be registered as a subscriber.

Comment: @aef In that particular case (first link), the model which was built there was needed only "on demand", so we didn't need to continuously build it. I have some improved version of that, which allows to "close to continuous work" (with 5 minutes lag or something like that), which is perfect for many cases, and it still relies only on having message queue. Alternative would be to write your own scheduler for some log (not queue) tool. Persistent projections is also something I want to add for RES, but I'm not sure when yet, and how hard it will be to make it relatively scheduler agnostic.